# How to get URL of the newly posted Facebook post via Graph API from returned response?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This:

```
$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
echo $graphNode['id'];
```

will output an id (a long number) of the newly created post.

How to get the URL where the new post is located form $graphNode?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with URL... If you want to query the Graph API for object details, you should be able to use

```
$request = $fb->request('GET', $graphNode['id']);
```